# Api getting called but recent data is not being fetched inside a service

Tags: android, api, service

I am having a Service in which after a specific time interval, i am calling the API and even API is called everytime but the newly added contents is not being updated. I couldn't find any reason why this is happening.

Let's say after every 1 minute the API is being called and the same data is returned. Once i close and restart the service, the data gets updated.

**EDIT**

```
public class MyCustomService extends Service {
    public int counter = 0;
    Context context;
    private List<List<Articles>> articlesList = null;
    private List<Articles> articlesListChild = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Articles> articlesListChildNew = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyCustomService(Context applicationContext) {
        super();
        context = applicationContext;
    }

    public MyCustomService() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        startTimer();
        context = this;
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        startTimer();
    }

    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;

    public void startTimer() {
        timer = new Timer();
        initializeTimerTask();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 10*1000, 10*1000);
    }

    public void initializeTimerTask() {
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
               checkForNewArticles();
            }
        };
    }

    public void checkForNewArticles() {
        Api.getClient().getHomeScreenContents(3, new Callback<ArticlesResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ArticlesResponse articlesResponse, Response response) {
                articlesList = articlesResponse.getHomeScreenData();
                for (int i = 0; i < articlesList.size(); i++) {
                    articlesListChildNew = articlesList.get(i);
                    articlesListChild.addAll(articlesListChildNew);
                }
                System.out.println("ARTICLE 1 : " + articlesListChild.get(0).getArticleHeading());
                System.out.println("ARTICLE 2 : " + articlesListChild.get(1).getArticleHeading());
                System.out.println("ARTICLE 3 : " + articlesListChild.get(2).getArticleHeading());
            }
            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.e("erroronlsArticles", error.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please include code snippets.

Comment: @MoA, i have added the code of Service class, kindly have a look.